# Output the Status of an Async Script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script that requires ~5 minutes to execute and complete. Everything takes place on one PHP page (includes, but no AJAX or anything). When the script completes, you're emailed a file.

What I would like is for the front end to simply accept the form submission and do it's thing behind the scenes, while pushing information through *if* the window remains open.

So, for instance, here would be the flow:

1. Fill out a form and submit.
2. Page confirms the form was submitted - free to close the window.
3. If the window remains open, give 'milestone' updates

   1. Query finished
   2. File generated
   3. Email sent

The goal would be to provide information if the user waits for it, but closing the window immediately after the form submits is perfectly acceptable and the email will still be received. I know I can submit the form via AJAX, but how can I pass back interim process completions rather than just a success callback?

Comment: I had a similar system implemented using coldfusion and cfflush with an iframe. When each milestone completed, i would cfflush to the iframe a script tag that did something to the parent page to indicate progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to have the client (the browser) poll the server on regular intervals for updates.  For example, you might have something like the following:

```
function checkStatus() {
    $.ajax( {
        url: "/CheckStatus",  // your AJAX handler, on the server
        success: function(data) {
            $('#status').text( data );
            if( data != 'Email sent' )
                setTimeout( checkStatus(), 100 );
        }
    } );
}
```

Then, after your form is submitted, simply call `checkStatus`.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your server side logic into a script that can run from the command line. Assuming you're on Linux you will then use the php exec() function to start a background process on your server that runs your script using the php command line program.

Then you will have your browser code poll the server regularly for updates.